# Error while loading data in netezza using external table logic

Tags: sql, jdbc, netezza

im getting following error while insertion of bulk data in netezza:

> ERROR:  Transaction rolled back by client

The query is

> INSERT  INTO 
>       source SELECT 
>       *  FROM 
>       EXTERNAL '%sourcefile.20130201%'  USING (REMOTESOURCE 'jdbc' DELIM '|');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the external table, try to create one first and then append to the distributed table.
Try something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEMP
(
  FIELD datatype,
  ...
  ...
)  USING (FILE('%sourcefile.20130201%') REMOTESOURCE 'jdbc' DELIM '|');
```

And then, once you have the external table created, you can append to a distributed table with:

```
INSERT INTO NZTABLE SELECT * FROM TEMP
```